# Pass Event from child component to parent component Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a parent component called `program-page` and it has a child component called `program-item` now I have a button on the `program-item` and what I want that button to do is to call a function on the parent component.. Im not sure how I would do something like this..

**program-page.component.html**

```
<app-program-header></app-program-header>
<app-week-display></app-week-display>
<app-program-item [item]="programItem"></app-program-item>
```

**program-page.component.ts**

```
someFunction()
```

**program-item.component.html**

```
<button>click me</button> // button I want to be able to call event on parent component
```

Im aware I could use an event emitter but Ive never used one before and not sure how I would implement it in this case, I havent seen any examples where clicking a button on a child component calls a function on the parent

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Angular has Input and Output, which can be used to provide data to a child component and send events to a parent component respectively.

You can do something like this.

**program-page.component.html**

```
<app-program-header></app-program-header>
<app-week-display></app-week-display>
<app-program-item [item]="programItem" (someEvent)="someFunction($event)"></app-program-item>
```

**program-item.component.ts**

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
....
@Output() someEvent = new EventEmitter();
```

**program-item.component.html**

```
<button (click)="someEvent.emit('data')">click me</button>
```

Primitive usage of Input and Output
[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbofnk)

Comment: In `program-page.component.html`, if you want to access the `data`, it actually should be `(someEvent)="someFunction($event)"`

Comment: It looks like the `@Output()` variable is defined in the parent component here. But in the given link its defined in the child component. Which one is right ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa you are right, it should be in the child component, stackblitz example is correct. Edited the answer.