# Angular (Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addControl') - Change form value in child component

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to update the form value from the child component. Here is the parent component:

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
     priority: [this.editPriority, Validators.nullValidator],
     . 
     .
     .
  });
 }
```

**app.component.html**

```
  <div *ngIf="editType === 'priority'">
    <app-child[form]="form"></app-child>
  </div>
```

child.component.ts:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

child.component.html:

```
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <label for="priority"> Priority</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="priority" name="priority" formControlName="priority"
           placeholder="priority">
  </div>
```

I tried like [this stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-form-validation-shb7v9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) but I got the below error:

*TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addControl')*

I tried adding:

```
this.form.addControl('priority', new FormControl());
```

inside `ngOnInit`but still I got the error.

Any suggestions for updating data through the child component?

Comment: You don't have a `FormGroup` variable named `formGroup`. You do have one named `form`, though. Could be a typo, could be the problem.

Comment: that was a typo. I tried form, not formGroup. modified it. thanks for your comment.

Comment: Try moving the control assignment into the `OnChanges` lifecycle method.

Comment: @FarzanNajipour, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Farzan. I use Angular event emitters, where the child calls a function in the parent (or vice-versa) when needed. This function exists in the parent or child and is called when needed, including the ability to pass parameters. Not sure if it works for your situation, but I know it works quite well for me very often.

Here is a simple example: [Pass Event from child component to parent component Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897465/pass-event-from-child-component-to-parent-component-angular-5)

Comment: this is a general way to pass data between parent and child. in this case, the form has more than 10 fields including the priority field. so for every data changing, I should emit data that is not the best way to communicate. The more important thing is I gave the error I mentioned even before changing data.